# $n^{th}-$ derivative of $\frac 1x {\cot\,(\frac {\pi x}2)}$?

Tags: real-analysis

To calculate the convergence radius of a series I need to know the $n^{th}-$ derivative of $\frac 1x  {\cot\,(\frac {\pi x}2)}$. You can write it also as $\frac 1{x \tan(\frac {\pi x}2)}$.Is there a way to obtain result in a closed simple form? Thanks

Comment: I need the n-th derivative of 1/(x tan(pi x/2)) or 1/(-1+e^(i pi x)) or 1/(-x+xe^(i pi x)) wich leads to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you need to know the $n$-th derivative in closed form.  The radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series of a function $f(z)$ is the supremum of $r$ such that $f(z)$ is analytic in the disk
$\{z \in \mathbb C: |z| < r\}$.  Where are the (non-removable) singularities of $\cot(\pi z/2)/z$?

Comment: well i would say at z=0 and z=2 for example.

Comment: Dear Robert so z=0 is a removable singularitie?and what is with z=2?

Comment: Dear Robert the n-th derivative of cot(pi x/2)/x is the coefficient of a series so i have to compute it,i dont understand your answer.

Comment: The fact that $f(x) = \cot(\pi x/2)/x)$ has some non-removable singularities implies that $f^{(n)}(x) R^n/n!$ is unbounded for some $R>0$, and then since $n! r^n/R^n \to \infty$ for $r > 0$, a series whose coefficients are $f^{(n)}(x)$ will have radius of convergence $0$.

Comment: I need the n-th derivative in a process of calculating the convergence radius ,your answer is not helpfull.

Comment: I need the n-th derivative of 1/(x tan(pi x/2)) or 1/(-1+e^(i pi x)) or 1/(-x+xe^(i pi x))